# Phonegap, jQuery Mobile and iframe

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, iframe

I have a mobile application written using phonegap and jquery mobile. There are few places where i am opening a mobile web page in popup, due to security reasons.

Is there any way to have mobile web inserted inside application? Is it OK to use iframe or there are better ways to do it?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not find any other solution apart from iFrame. But you are going to have problems with some android versions, mainly 2.X versions.

There another solution but it can't be used as a popup: [Phonegap childbrowser plugin](http://build.phonegap.com/blog/childbrowser-plugin)